# Build.Reason showing IndividualCI other than ResourceTrigger in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to trigger an Azure Pipeline that exists in the repository "**A**" from the repository "**B**".

So any change that would happen in the repo "**B**" will trigger the pipeline in the repo "**A**".

You'll find the defintion of my pipeline below. I am printing the different variables for debugging purposes.

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: B
      type: git
      name: TestProject/B
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
          - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo ${{ variables['Build.Reason'] }}
    echo ${{ variables['resources.triggeringAlias'] }}
    echo ${{ variables['resources.triggeringCategory'] }}
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

When I push a change into the repo "**B**", the pipeline gets triggered and starts running, but unfortunately the build reason is "*IndividualCI*" and not "*ResourceTrigger*" as mentionned in the documentation, so of course the **resources.*** variables are empty.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried using `Build.Repository.Name` to get the triggering repository's name like this:

```
steps:
- script: echo ${{ variables['Build.Repository.Name'] }}
```

When I edit the "**B**" repository to trigger the pipeline, I always keep getting "*IndividualCI*" for the `Build.Reason` predefined variable and I get "**A**" as the output of the script.

After some testing, I finally got the source repository name using this syntax:

```
steps:
- script: echo $(Build.Repository.Name)
```

Even though the details, I found a solution to my main issue, which is getting the triggering repository's name (just by changing the syntax).